# Installing SAP Advantage Database Server in Linux

Tags: linux, advantage-database-server

I would like to setup a linux virtual machine with SAP Advantage Database Server, for development purposes.

I have registered for a free trial in SAP's site, but the only links I see are for Windows 32 and 64 bits.

Can I setup Advantage Database Server under linux? If so, can someone point me to where I can download the setup, and hopefully some installation instructions as I have no prior experience with SAP Advantage Database Server?

Thank you.

Comment: Try the instructions here: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html?installing_the_advantage_datab.htm

Comment: SAP is barely supporting ADS anymore, I would recommend you to switch to a different database if you can. If you really want to use it, you should contact SAP via email.

Comment: Here is a list of content on the SAP website that is tagged ADS: https://www.sap.com/community/tag.html?id=67838200100800005437

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff thanks a lot for that link! I can see there are installation instructions for linux, which is a good start. However, I still face one problem that I don't see answered in that link, which is where I can find the download for the linux version. I can't seem to find that.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I have found a linux version here: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19&Product=25&Platform=10 but it's not version 12, it's version 11, which apparently is not the current release.

Comment: The link you found is the full version, you need a serial number with that. Also that is an old version, yes. There used to be a free 2-user development version of the server. Your best bet is to contact SAP directly, sorry.